# SHACL equivalent of JSON-Schema "uniqueItems"

Tags: rdf, jsonschema, shacl

So I'm tasked with converting a JSON-Schema describing an ontology to SHACL.

JSON-Schema has the `uniqueItems` construct, which, as the name suggests, forces all elements in an array to be unique. For my purposes, only elements of type String are considered.

Is there a similar construct in SHACL? `sh:disjoint` requires explicit unique paths so it doesn't apply. I'm considering creating a SPARQL constraint, though since my instances are all anonymous nodes, I haven't been able to get it to work yet.

Edit: Adding examples

Valid JSON:

```json
{
                "name": "Robert Lewandowski",
                "mbox": "robert@bayern.de",
                "contributor_id": {
                    "identifier": "https://orcid.org/TEST",
                    "type": "orcid"
                },
                "role": [
                    "ContactPerson",
                    "DataManager"
                ]
            }
```

Invalid JSON:

```json
{
                "name": "Robert Lewandowski",
                "mbox": "robert@bayern.de",
                "contributor_id": {
                    "identifier": "https://orcid.org/TEST",
                    "type": "orcid"
                },
                "role": [
                    "ContactPerson",
                    "ContactPerson"
                ]
            }
```

Valid TTL:

```
madmp:contributor [ foaf:mbox "robert@bayern.de" ;
                    foaf:name "Robert Lewandowski" ;
                    madmp:contributor_id  [ terms:identifier "https://orcid.org/TEST" ;
                                           madmp:identifier_type  "orcid"
                                          ] ;
                    madmp:role ( "ContactPerson" "DataManager")
                  ] ;
```

Invalid TTL:

```
madmp:contributor [ foaf:mbox "robert@bayern.de" ;
                    foaf:name "Robert Lewandowski" ;
                    madmp:contributor_id  [ terms:identifier "https://orcid.org/TEST" ;
                                           madmp:identifier_type  "orcid"
                                          ] ;
                    madmp:role ( "ContactPerson" "ContactPerson")
```

Comment: Could you add examples of good and bad data to the question? I think it would help to see how `sh:disjoint` does (indeed not) apply and what could be used.

Comment: @BenCompanjen Added examples

Comment: I don't see a solution without SHACL-SPARQL here. In general, support for rdf:Lists is rather limited in SHACL as most RDF ontologies prefer using simple properties (such as madmp:role "ContactPerson", "DataManager" in Turtle) and there cannot be duplicates in that design. Is the order really so important here that you cannot just use a normal (object) property?

Comment: @HolgerKnublauch I don't think anyone is a fan of rdf:List, but that's just what Apache Jena outputs when converting the json serialization to Turtle. I've managed to write a SPARQL constraint for this which I will post as an answer here, as soon as I make sure it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is a solution I came up with. It uses the [dash vocabulary](http://datashapes.org/) to first make sure the `rdf:List` structure is valid. The SPARQL constraint then makes sure that the values are unique.

It might not be pretty, but it works for me.

```
sh:property [
            sh:path madmp:role;
            sh:name "The Role Schema";
            sh:description "Type of contributor";
            sh:node dash:ListShape;
            sh:minCount 1 ;
            sh:property [
                sh:path ( [ sh:zeroOrMorePath rdf:rest ] rdf:first ) ;
                sh:datatype xsd:string ;
                sh:minCount 1 ;
            ]
        ];
        sh:sparql [
            sh:message "Contributor {?name} has role {?role} more than once ({?roleCount} times).";
            sh:prefixes (madmp: rdf: foaf:);
            sh:select """
              PREFIX madmp: <https://w3id.org/madmp/terms#>
              PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
              prefix foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

              SELECT $this ?role ?name (COUNT(?role) AS ?roleCount)
              WHERE {
                  $this $PATH ?contributor.
                  ?contributor madmp:role/rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?role;
                  foaf:name ?name
              }
              GROUP BY $this ?name ?role
              HAVING (?roleCount > 1)
            """
        ]
```